# Brackets/Parens in Ruby Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm getting a warning and an error:

```
rubytime.rb:18: warning: character class has `[' without escape
rubytime.rb:18: unmatched ): /^(\w+).*\([([\d]+)\+]?(\d\d):(\d\d)\)\s*$/
```

for this line:

```
if line =~ /^(\w+).*\([([\d]+)\+]?(\d\d):(\d\d)\)\s*$/
```

I've checked a few times and the parens/brackets seem to line up, though perhaps (having recently done perl) I'm making a false assumption about Regexps in Ruby.

Comment: Why the nested brackets?  Are you expecting brackets in your data?

Comment: I dint find any errors running this at http://tryruby.org. Can you provide a gist or pastebin of the code not working?

Comment: What exactly do you intend by `[([\d]+)\+]`? You can't nest character classes. This is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[([\d]+)\+]?
```

Did you mean...

```
(([\d]+)\+)?
```

---

Also, `[\d]` is equivalent to `\d`, so you could really write it as...

```
((\d+)\+)?
```

---

If you don't want the outer group to be a matching group, you can use the non-matching `(?: )`:

```
(?:(\d+)\+)?
```

Comment: This last one is what Chris is most likely looking for.  Pretty much what I was going to suggest.  Intuitively, I think this is what he was trying to accomplish.  `(?:(\d+)\+)?` Let's see.

Comment: The first sequence, if it exists (and it may not) is 1 or more numbers followed by a literal +. Would the last one accomplish that? I guess I got confused with grouping when I wasn't going to use the group (via $1, $2, etc) later.

Comment: Yes, the last version will match that. `\d+` is one or more digits; `\+` is a literal plus, and `(?: )` is a non-capturing group, same as `()` but without adding a capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you need literal brackets, you need to escape them. `\[ \]`. An unescaped bracket starts a "character class" such as `[abc]` which accepts `a` or `b` or `c`. These can't be nested.